# How can I solve the improper integral $\int_{1}^\infty {dx \over {(x+1)(x+2)}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

$$\int_{1}^\infty {dx \over {(x+1)(x+2)}}$$

I have the indefinite integral solved for:

$$\ln(x+1)-\ln(x+2) + C$$

But I don't know how to finish with $[1, \infty]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\ln(x+1)-\ln(x+2)=\ln\frac{x+1}{x+2}=\ln\frac{1+\frac 1x}{1+\frac 2x}.$$

Comment: But then when you take the limit doesnt it just equal ln(1/1) = 0?

Comment: @Jay: Yes, it does. But note that the answer is not $0$.

Comment: I know that it is ln(3/2), but I just don't see how, If you take the limit it just equals ln(0)-ln(0) I thought

Comment: @Jay: To avoid $\ln(\infty)-\ln(\infty)$, we have $\ln\frac{x+1}{x+2}$.

Comment: thanks i get it now, i wasn't plugging in correctly

Answer (score 2):

Use

$$\ln(x+1)-\ln(x+2)=\ln\left(\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: split the fraction in two, then use the improper integral

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{1}^{M}\frac{dx}{(x+1)(x+2)}=\int_{1}^{M}\frac{dx}{x+1}-\int_{1}^{M}\frac{dx}{x+2}=\int_{1}^{M}\frac{dx}{x+1}-\int_{2}^{M+1}\frac{dx}{x+1}$$
hence:
$$\int_{1}^{M}\frac{dx}{(x+1)(x+2)}=\int_{1}^{2}\frac{dx}{x+1}-\int_{M}^{M+1}\frac{dx}{x+1}=\log\frac{3}{2}+O\left(\frac{1}{M}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\ln (\frac{x+1}{x+2})=\ln(\frac{1+1/x}{1+2/x})$$

Answer (score 0):

To find the "value" at $+ \infty$, notice that

$$\ln(x+1) - \ln(x+2) = \ln \left( \frac{x+1}{x+2} \right)$$

From here the limit is easy to calculate

Answer (score -1):

$\ln(x+1)-\ln(x+2) + C = \ln(\frac{x+1}{x+2}) + C$ evaluated at 1 and $\infty$ gives $\ln(\frac{\infty}{\infty}) - \ln\frac{2}{3}=\ln\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: Writting $\ln ( \frac{\infty}{\infty} )$ is ugly and dangerous. What about $\ln(x^2/(x+1) ) $ that is also "$\ln ( \frac{\infty}{\infty} )$"?

Comment: point taken, however, it was implied that the $\ln(\frac{\infty}{\infty})$ was $\ln(\frac{1+x}{2+x})$